# How to expose WCF method?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'd like to access a WCF method via url.  For example:

localhost:8080/TestService.svc/MyMethod

When I do the above, I get a webpage cannot be found.  In the Interface file, I have added the following above MyMethod.

```
[WebGet]  
[OperationContract]  
void MyMethod();
```

but that didn't change anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: How are you attempting to consume this service?  Have you generated a service proxy?

Answer (score 1):

How does your web.config look like?  Are you using REST?

Have you looked at below post?
[Making a WCF Web Service work with GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944678/making-a-wcf-web-service-work-with-get-requests)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. You need to use REST to do what you want.
Or use a Controller/Action (if this is MVC) that will create a proxy object to consume the service e.g.

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
client.MyMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [nice example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx) on how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I think the quickest solution is to use a factory. It seems likely they would want a restful service so if you follow this guide you wont even need to specify anything in the web.config. See the first answer on this question.

[Bare Minimum Configuration for RESTful WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139821/bare-minimum-configration-for-restful-wcf)